# Color encoding for shell script

Tags: shell-script, vim, ksh

I using KSH shell as my linux environment. I am writing shell script for one of my project. Currently shell script does not shows color encoding for variable ,etc. It comes in black and white mode. How do i enable color encoding in VI editor?

I tried `:syntax on`  but its not working. I did bit of googling and found that shell.vim is required for color encoding in VI editor. But still not sure how do i get it.

Please advice here.

Comment: Which version of Vim? How did you install it?

Comment: What OS?  Please edit post to include the output of `vim --version`.

Comment: I am using vim 7.2 version.  Issue has been resolved now. I did yum install vim-enhanced and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the CentOS VM which you asked about earlier, you need the vim-enhanced package to have color-syntax. The base install may provide only vim-minimal, which does not do this. Also, it makes a difference whether you invoke it as "vi" or "vim". The latter turns on the enhancements automatically.

For additional reading:

- [VI and VIM Syntax Highlighting on Fedora / CentOS / Red Hat (RHEL)](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/vi-vim-syntax-highlighting-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/?PageSpeed=noscript)
- [How to have colors in vim when :syntax on does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997530/how-to-have-colors-in-vim-when-syntax-on-does-nothing)

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Just for your info , I am not using CentOS here. I  am using RedHat.